# requests claims self-signed cert has an IP address mismatch when server enforces https

Tags: python, ssl

This is a test in my CI pipeline that began failing in the last 3 months.

I've checked and double checked that the certificate is good. Here is the result of `openssl x509 -text -noout -in the-cert.crt`:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            <redacted>
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: CN = 172.17.0.2
        Validity
            Not Before: Jul 19 16:51:57 2023 GMT
            Not After : Jul 18 16:51:57 2024 GMT
        Subject: CN = 172.17.0.2
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    <redacted>
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                <redacted>
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                <redacted>
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
    Signature Value:
        <redacted>
```

I need the following to pass:

```py
res2 = requests.get('http://172.17.0.2/index.html', timeout=15, verify="/home/mrx/appx/the-cert.crt")
```

Instead I get the error:

```py
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='172.17.0.2', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /index.html (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch, certificate is not valid for '172.17.0.2'. (_ssl.c:997)")))
```

Port 443 was bugging me. It doesn't change if I specify "https" but obviously I had port 80 being forwarded to 443 in my server configuration.

This works from the shell:

```
curl https://172.17.0.2/index.html --cacert the-cert.crt
```

The plain http version returns a 301 redirect. If I comment out the `listen 443` in the server block, everything (including the `request`) works, but distorts the original test.

Any ideas for a neat (other than try-catch-branch) fix?

requests 2.31.0, python 3.10.6, (ubuntu 22.04)

I tried running nginx on Debian from 2022, bullseye-slim, right up to current bookworm. Bookworm provided nginx 1.22.1.

Comment: This was working, but with incomplete version pinning (just the OS base layer) it's still anyone's guess what shifted.

Comment: In short: the IP address should be given in the certificate as subject alternative name with type IP - not as CN.